# Search isanswered:yes and isanswered:no do not work as intended

Tags: bug, search

Update: this is connected to question on Meta: [The “isanswered” search parameter documentation is incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250626/296059).

---

From [the searching reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching): (emphasis and formatting mine)

> **isanswered:**
>
> - yes/true/1 **returns only questions** that have at least one accepted or positively-scored answer;
> - no/false/0 **returns only questions** with no accepted or positively-scored answers.

The **`isanswered:no` is obviously invalid.** It returns answers, when it should not.

Moreover, the **share of unanswered results** seems to be around 3 times more than answered, which is not true. (That's because the `isanswered:no` counts answers too).

[`isanswered:yes`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes)

[Large search results image for `isanswered:yes`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7blW.png)

[`isanswered:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ano)

[Large search results image for `isanswered:no`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOTnx.png)

Moreover, both [`isanswered:no isanswered:yes`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ano%20isanswered%3Ayes) and [`isanswered:yes isanswered:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes%20isanswered%3Ano) are valid and different.

Is this a bug? Am I using the syntax incorrectly?

Comment: `isanswered:no` here is not assuming `is:question`, which throws your stats out the window. Try explicitly `isanswered:no is:q`.

Comment: @Braiam look at this: it should return an empty list. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aanswer

Comment: @Braiam at least this works as it should: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ano+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Related: [The “isanswered” search parameter documentation is incorrect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250626). This is in addition to it being somewhat buggy in the way you described: you do need additional parameters that pertain specifically to questions, otherwise the results are nonsensical.

Comment: @1999 ok, seems like my question is a duplicate of the older one on Meta.

Comment: Not entirely; the fact that the search returns answers isn't mentioned there. (I noticed it too, but it's easy to work around, so I didn't bother bringing it up). This search parameter was undocumented for a long time, only used for something internally; this is likely why it's less polished than others.

Comment: @1999 replaced "duplicate" with "connected to".